# Is a topological category a Grothendieck site?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

I take the definition of a topological category from Segal and (later) Moerdijk. So this is a small category with topologies on the set of objects and the set of morphisms, such that the domain map, the codomain map, the identity map and the composition map are continuous.

Moreover, one can take the classifying topos $\mathcal B\mathbf C$ of such a category, as defined in Moerdjik, *Classifying spaces and classifying topos*. This is actually a Grothendieck topos, but who is a site of definition? 
Moerdijk says that one can prove that this is a topos by checking the Giraud axioms, but I would rather see a direct evidence, so a site $D$ and a Grothendieck topology s.t. $\mathcal B\mathbf C\cong Sh(D,J)$.

So in brief: in what sense is a topological category (e.g. a topological groupoid) a site in the sense of Grothendieck topologies?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might be able to diagonalize [this description](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sheaves+on+a+simplicial+topological+space) to get what you're looking for. Oddly, I feel like this question is usually asked the other way around -- that the big theorem is "[every site of definition can be improved to a localic groupoid](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/classifying+topos+of+a+localic+groupoid)" (topological groupoid if the topos has enough points).

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that theorem(s). I was actually looking for the "easy arrow", and what you linked seems to suffice. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I still fail to see where the Grothendieck topology comes from. Can someone give me a little hint? Mac Lane and Moerdijk, _Sheaves in Geometry and Logic_, gives the answer in the case of a topological group and its topos of equivariant sheaves, but I don't think that point of view generalises to arbitrary topological categories. Thanks.

Comment: I guess the canonical coverage does not count?

Comment: The point is: does it take into account the topology on morphisms? I mean, you suggest to treat the category as an ordinary topological space, right? Bu this involves only objects. Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: I was suggesting to take $D = BC$ with the canonical coverage. So, yes, I was ignoring $C$ and its topology completely. Do you want $D$ to be $C$ (sort of) and $J$ to be cooked up from the topology of $C$ in some way?

Comment: I'm sorry, I had completely misinterpreted your words: this would certainly suffice! Could you give me a reference about what the canonical coverage of $BC$ is?

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/canonical+topology and the references therein.

Comment: Nonetheless, I am curious to see if there is a Grothendieck topology on $C$ giving rise to $BC$.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reference. Could you give me an idea about how to prove $Sh_{canonical}(BC)=BC$ without already knowing that $BC$ is a Grothendieck topos?

Comment: No, not really. In general, it should boil down to the verification of Girard's axioms, but maybe there is a simpler way in this case, or even better, a more suited base site. I haven't thought this through yet.